# Migrating a relationship name change in Core-Data

Tags: core-data

How does one properly migrate a relationship name change in a core data model?

We have a version that went live with a simple name change(done on different branches) on the relationship, and its broken migration..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests on migrations are a hard lesson :)

You can change the name of a property (attribute or relationship) as long as you also update the "Renaming ID" of the property to the name that was in the source model.

Lightweight migration will take it from there.